# Recoding varied length variable in SAS where every observation is a different value

Tags: regex, sas

Please help me, a novice SAS user, figure this one out!

I have a variable (PERMITCL) that I need to recode.  There are a few problems, however.  First, the variable is different for almost every observation.  Second, the length of the variable is also different in some cases.

Here are a few examples of observations:

```
01-01IIP
05-04
19-06ID
07-05
IIP
```

I want to know how many observations contain `IIP`.

I've tried using:

```
where prxmatch("m/IIP/oi", PERMITCL);
```

This is fine to some extent, but I'm still not happy with it. First, it doesn't keep any of the other observations; I'd prefer to keep them as zeroes or another identifier for later.  Second, I still can't easily see how many total IIPs there are; a table yields a different line for each `##-##IIP` and plain `IIP`.

How can I fix my issues?

Comment: Why does this question have a Perl tag?

Comment: PRXMATCH() is a SAS function that uses perl style regular expressions.

Comment: [tag:regex] is appropriate for questions about `prxmatch`, not [tag:perl].

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a `WHERE` statement is to subset.  Sounds like instead you want to calculate a new variable that you then sum or use for other things.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  flag = prxmatch("m/IIP/oi",PERMITCL);
run;

proc freq ;
  tables flag ;
run;
```

The PRXMATCH() will return the location of the text in the string. If you want to convert it to a binary result then you could add more code. So you could do this instead:

```
  flag = (0 ne prxmatch("m/IIP/oi",PERMITCL)) ;
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem.